# What is the difference between Disk IO Utilisation and Disk IO Saturation in Grafana?

Tags: performance-testing, grafana, disk-io

Our product uses the grafana tool to monitor a multi node, cpu, executor application. I don't know much as I am new in this field. At a particular moment I noticed that the "Disk IO Saturation" is close to 100% while the Utilisation is very less. Can anyone explain the difference between these two in more depth or point to any resource from where I can read about it?
[image]

Comment: Where do this values come from? Grafana does not measure anything. It is just a visualization tool for value from multiple data sources. This question is labeled wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there somewhere I can read about these? It's a bit confusing, disk utilisation is, according to my understanding is how much disk is being used, which in this case looks like close to 0%. On other hands, I think disk saturation should be how much time the disk was saturated (100% used) but why is this touching 100% sometimes? That I don't understand.